# Imagens grandes corrompidas ou truncadas ao puxar do SQL server com PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, sql-server

Estou buscando imagens do banco SQL-server através do PHP e jQuery+AJAX. A imagem quando é pequena carrega tudo completinho, mas quando a imagem é um pouco grande da esse erro no JavaScript:

> Image corrupt or truncated: data:image/jpg;base64,/9j/4TSPRXhpZgAASUkqAAgAAAARAA4BAgAgAAAA2gAAAA8BAgAFAAAA+gAAABAB...

E a imagem fica conforme abaixo, já fiz um teste abrindo o arquivo direto uma pagina PHP sem o uso do jQuery+AJAX e dá o mesmo problema, então eu creio que o problema seja no PHP ou no SQL-server.

[image]

```
mssql_connect('192.168.1.xxx', 'sa', 'senhaDoBanco');
mssql_select_db('database');
$query = "exec sp_funcionarioDetalhes";            
$result = mssql_query($query);
$obj = mssql_fetch_object($result);
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
echo $array[1]->fun_foto;
```

Vou ser mais técnico, talvez assim alguém dê mais importância ao problema.
vou passar todos os códigos.
arquivo funcionarioDetalhes.html

```
<?php
/*
 * Maison K. Sakamoto 03/11/2014 - Funcionário Detalhes
 */
session_start('login'); 
if(!@$_SESSION["conectado"]=='sim'){
        echo "<script language='JavaScript'>
                    alert('Voce nao esta conectado, Favor logar novamente.');
                    window.location = '../index.php';
                </script>";             
}    
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Sistemas BTR - Transportes</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="../css/grid/style.css" />

    <style type="text/css">                                                           
        #ui-datepicker-div { line-height: 1; }
        #fun_ctps { font-size: 8pt; }
        .container_12 { width: 76%; padding-top: 30px; }            
        .container_12 .grid_8 { width: 626px; margin-top: 10px; }
        .container_12 .grid_4 { width: 302px; margin-top: 10px; }
        .container_12 .grid_2 { margin-top: 10px; }
        .container_12 .grid_2.foto{ margin-top: -161px; }
        .grid_11 fieldset { border: 1px dotted #666; }
        .right { float: right; }
        .text-right { text-align: right; }
        .ui-widget-content { border: 1px solid #aaaaaa; }                                    
        .ui-button { -moz-user-select: none; } /* PARA QUE O TEXTO DO BOTAO NAO SEJA SELECIONADO COM O MOUSE*/
        .field-pequeno { width: 112px; }     
        .field-principal { min-height: 300px; }
        .foto{ height: 207px; }
        #fun_foto img { max-width: 140px; max-height: 202px; }
        .listaFuncionario { min-height: 250px; }
        .grid_4.input { width: 300px; }
        .coluna1 input {
            border: medium none;
            font-family: Verdana;
            font-size: 12px;
            height: 20px;
            text-align: center;
            width: 140px;
        }            
        .coluna1 textarea {
            border: medium none;
            font-family: Verdana;
            font-size: 11px;
            height: 77px;
            line-height: 14px;
            overflow: hidden;
            resize: none;
            width: 300px;
        }            
    </style>
</head>
<div class="container_12">    
    <fieldset class="field-principal ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
        <legend class="ui-widget ui-widget-header ui-corner-all">Funcionário - Detalhes</legend>
        <div class="grid_4 omega">
            <fieldset class="ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all listaFuncionario">
                <legend>NOME</legend>
                <div id="div_fun" class="grid_3 alpha"></div>
            </fieldset>

        </div>
        <div class="grid_11 omega">                
            <fieldset class="grid_2 alpha coluna1"> <legend>FILIAL</legend>     <input id="fun_filial" type="text" readonly=""/> </fieldset>
            <fieldset class="grid_2 alpha coluna1"> <legend>NASCIMENTO</legend> <input id="fun_dt_nascimento" type="text" readonly=""/> </fieldset>
            <fieldset class="grid_2 alpha coluna1"> <legend>ADMISSÃO</legend>   <input id="fun_dt_admissao" type="text" readonly=""/> </fieldset>
            <fieldset class="grid_2 alpha coluna1"> <legend>DEMISSÃO</legend>   <input id="fun_dt_demissao" type="text" readonly=""/> </fieldset>
            <fieldset class="grid_2 alpha coluna1"> <legend>FÉRIAS</legend>     <input id="fun_dt_ferias" type="text" readonly=""/> </fieldset>


            <fieldset class="grid_2 alpha coluna1"> <legend>CPF</legend>        <input id="fun_cpf" type="text" /> </fieldset>
            <fieldset class="grid_2 alpha coluna1"> <legend>PIS</legend>        <input id="fun_pis" type="text" readonly=""/> </fieldset>
            <fieldset class="grid_2 alpha coluna1"> <legend>CTPS</legend>       <input id="fun_ctps" type="text" readonly=""/> </fieldset>
            <fieldset class="grid_2 alpha coluna1"> <legend>SALÁRIO</legend>    <input id="fun_salario" type="text" readonly=""/> </fieldset>                

            <fieldset class="grid_4 alpha coluna1"> <legend>ENDEREÇO</legend>   <textarea id="fun_endereco" readonly=""/> </fieldset>
            <fieldset class="grid_2 alpha coluna1"> <legend>CEP</legend>        <input id="fun_cep" type="text" readonly=""/> </fieldset>
            <fieldset class="grid_2 alpha coluna1"> <legend>CIDADE</legend>     <input id="fun_cidade" type="text" readonly=""> </fieldset>
            <fieldset class="grid_4 alpha coluna1"> <legend>CARGO</legend>     <input id="fun_cargo" type="text" readonly=""> </fieldset>                

            <fieldset class="grid_8 alpha coluna1"> <legend>AÇÕES</legend>
                <button id="btGravar" >Gravar Alteração</button>
                <button id="btListaFerias">Imprimir Lista de Férias</button>
                <button id="btDadosFun">Imprimir Dados do Funcionário</button>
            </fieldset>

            <fieldset class="grid_2 alpha coluna1 foto"> <legend>FOTO</legend>  <div id="fun_foto"></div> </fieldset>

        </div>        
    </fieldset>
</div>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../js/jqwidgets-ver3.4.0/jqwidgets/styles/jqx.base.css"    type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jqwidgets-ver3.4.0/jqwidgets/jqxcore.js">    </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jqwidgets-ver3.4.0/jqwidgets/jqxmenu.js">    </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jqwidgets-ver3.4.0/jqwidgets/jqxbuttons.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jqwidgets-ver3.4.0/jqwidgets/jqxbuttons.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jqwidgets-ver3.4.0/jqwidgets/jqxscrollbar.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jqwidgets-ver3.4.0/jqwidgets/jqxdata.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jqwidgets-ver3.4.0/jqwidgets/jqxlistbox.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jqwidgets-ver3.4.0/jqwidgets/jqxgrid.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jqwidgets-ver3.4.0/jqwidgets/jqxgrid.columnsresize.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jqwidgets-ver3.4.0/jqwidgets/jqxgrid.sort.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jqwidgets-ver3.4.0/jqwidgets/jqxgrid.selection.js"></script>        
<script type="text/javascript">
   loadjscssfile('../js/rh/funcionarioDetalhes.js','js');
</script>
</html>
```

Arquivo funcionarioDetalhes.js

```
    /* 
 * MAISON K. SAKAMOTO - 03/11/2014 - CRIAÇÃO DO ARQUIVO
 */

var fun= {};

fun.start=function(){
    $('button').button();
    $('#btGravar').click(function(){ });
    $('#btListaFerias').click(function(){ });
    $('#btDadosFun').click(function(){ });
    fun.buscarFuncionarios();
};

fun.buscarFuncionarios=function(){
    var array = custom.ajax(new Object(),'buscarFuncionarios','../view/rh/vFuncionarioDetalhes.php');
    fun.setListaFuncionarios(array);
};

fun.setListaFuncionarios=function(json){    
    $("#div_fun").jqxListBox({
            source: json, width: 280, height: 500, selectedIndex: 0,
            displayMember: 'fun_nome', valueMember: 'fun_id'
    });        
    $("#div_fun").bind('select', function(event){
        if (event.args){
            var obj = event.args.item.originalItem;
            fun.preencheForm(obj);
        }
    });                                                       
    var t = $("#div_fun").jqxListBox('getSelectedItem');
    fun.preencheForm(t.originalItem);
};

fun.preencheForm = function(obj){
    $("#fun_filial").val( obj.unidade );
    $("#fun_dt_nascimento").val( obj.fun_dt_nascimento );
    $("#fun_dt_admissao").val( obj.fun_dt_admissao );
    $("#fun_dt_demissao").val( obj.fun_dt_demissao );
    $("#fun_dt_ferias").val( obj.fun_dt_ferias );
    $("#fun_cargo").val( obj.fun_cargo );
    $("#fun_cpf").val( obj.fun_cpf );
    $("#fun_pis").val( obj.fun_pis );
    $("#fun_ctps").val( obj.fun_ctps_numero + "" +obj.fun_ctps_serie+ " " +obj.fun_ctps_uf);
    $("#fun_salario").val( obj.fun_salario );
    $("#fun_endereco").val( obj.fun_endereco +' \r\nNº '+obj.fun_n_endereco+' \r\n'+obj.fun_bairro );
    $("#fun_cep").val( obj.fun_cep );
    $("#fun_cidade").val( obj.fun_cidade );    
    //$("#fun_foto").empty().append( $('<img>').attr('src',"data:image/png;base64," + obj.fun_foto) );
    var img = $('<img>').attr('src',"data:image/jpg;base64," + obj.fun_foto);
    $("#fun_foto").empty().append( img );
};

fun.start();
```

Arquivo vFuncionario.php (viewer)

```
include_once '../../controller/OpenDB.php';
include_once '../../controller/ColFuncionario.php';

@session_start('login'); 

$colFuncionario = new ColFuncionario();
$c = new OpenDB();                                                  // CLASSE DO BANCO DE DADOS    

$funcao = $_REQUEST['funcao'];    
call_user_func($funcao);

function buscarFuncionarios(){
    global $colFuncionario; 
    global $c;
    $c->conCordilheira();
    $array = $colFuncionario->buscarFuncionarios();
    echo json_encode( $array );
}
```

Arquivo ColFuncionario.php ( controller )

```
    <?php
/*
 * Autor: Maison K. Sakamoto
 * Revisao: 0
 * Data: 25/07/2012
 *
 * Descricao: 
 * Controle de Funcionario
 */
class ColFuncionario{

        public function __construct(){

        }

        public function inserirFuncionario($obj){
            //STRTOUPPER RESOLVIDO PROBLEMA DE ACENTUAÇÃO EM MAIUSCULAS
            $query = "insert into tab_funcionario(cargo_id,func_nome,func_hab,func_hab_venc,func_cpf) values 
                ($obj->cargo_id,'".strtoupper(strtr($obj->func_nome,"áéíóúâêôãõàèìòùç","ÁÉÍÓÚÂÊÔÃÕÀÈÌÒÙÇ")).
                    "','$obj->func_hab',STR_TO_DATE('$obj->func_hab_venc','%d/%m/%Y'),'$obj->func_cpf')";
            mysql_query($query);
            return "mysql_info: ".mysql_info()."<br/>"."mysql_error: ".mysql_error()."<br/>query: ".$query;
        }

        public function getCargos(){
            $query = "select * from tab_cargo";
            $result = mysql_query($query);
            while($obj = mysql_fetch_object($result)){
                $array[] = $obj;
            }                
            return $array;
        }

        public function getMotoristas(){
            $query = "select * from tab_funcionario where cargo_id = 1 and func_inativo is null ORDER BY func_nome";
            $result = mysql_query($query);
            while($obj = mysql_fetch_object($result)){
                $array[] = $obj;
            }                
            return $array;
        }

        // BUSCA FUNCIONARIOS DO SQL-SERVER BANCO DE DADOS CORDILHEIRA 
        public function buscarFuncionarios(){
            //ini_set('mssql.charset', 'UTF-8');
            $query = "exec sp_funcionarioDetalhes";            
            $result = mssql_query($query);
            while($obj = mssql_fetch_object($result)){ 
                $obj->fun_nome = mb_convert_encoding($obj->fun_nome, 'UTF-8');
                $obj->fun_cidade = mb_convert_encoding($obj->fun_cidade, 'UTF-8');
                $obj->unidade = mb_convert_encoding($obj->unidade, 'UTF-8');
                $obj->fun_endereco = mb_convert_encoding($obj->fun_endereco, 'UTF-8');
                $obj->fun_bairro = mb_convert_encoding($obj->fun_bairro, 'UTF-8');
                $obj->fun_cargo = mb_convert_encoding($obj->fun_cargo, 'UTF-8');
                $obj->fun_foto = base64_encode( $obj->fun_foto);
                $array[] = $obj;                 
            }
            return $array;
        }
}
```

Arquivo OpenDB.php

```
class OpenDB{
    public function conCordilheira(){   

        //1 passo - Conecta ao servidor SQL 2008 R2 Cordilheira
        $conn = mssql_connect('192.168.1.xxx', 'sa', 'senhaDoBanco');
                mssql_select_db('databaseDoMeuSqlServer');

        //$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

        if( $conn ) {
            return $conn;
             //echo "Connection established.<br />";
        }else{
             echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
             die( print_r(mssql_erro(), true));
        }

    }
}
```

resultado
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não tenho experiência com MSSQL, mas você pode tentar alterar os valores dessas três diretivas no PHP.INI, preferencialmente uma por vez e ver qual delas realmente funcionou, assim, caso solucione, você mesmo ajudará a comunidade.

```
mssql.textsize  = 2147483647
mssql.textlimit = 2147483647
odbc.defaultlrl = "100K"
```

Uma consideração a ser feita com respeito a terceira opção é que, pela documentação, o valor a ser passado é um inteiro, representando o número de bytes que serão passados para as variáveis quando campos longos forem lidos porém, de acordo com [essa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4500598/753531) no SOEN, em tempo de execução, você pode definir uma string.

Para definir um valor a uma diretiva do PHP em tempo de execução, use [ini_set()](http://www.php.net/ini_set):

```
ini_set("odbc.defaultlrl", "100K");
```

No exemplo acima ficou definido 100K que seriam 96K a mais que o padrão.

Vale salientar que as outras duas diretivas já estão nos valores máximos permitidos e que podem não ser alteradas via [ini_set()](http://www.php.net/ini_set) em versões antigas do PHP.

Espero que ajude

Comment: ja vou testar esses param 1 mim.

Comment: não deu certo :(

Comment: Só pra constar, as duas diretivas que precisavam ser feitas no PHP.INI foram descomentadas e depois de alteradas você reiniciou o servidor, certo? E a outra, você invocou ini_set() antes de fazer a consulta ao campo em questão, certo?

Comment: agora deu certo, testei certinho p/ ver qual parametro que faz a magica, é o mssql.textsize, eu não sabia o tamanho das imagens, mas tem mais de 2mb cada uma, e eu puxava num array de sei lá quantos funcionários, agora vou arrumar no php p/ diminuir essas imagens antes de enviar via ajax p/ pagina, valeu mesmo.

Answer (score 0):

Como funciona para imagens pequenas, pode ser problema de memória, tente aumentar a memoria disponível para o PHP e seu banco.

Aumentar memoria php.ini

```
memory_limit = 64M
```

.htaccess

```
php_value_memory_limit 64M
```

Tente aumentar a memória de alguma forma e teste o código outra vez, quem sabe realmente é isso.

Comment: vou ver e já te respondo

Comment: os dois parametros já esta com 128M

Comment: Coloca mais que isso, acho que 128 é pouco. Não custa tentar.